How to display a custom message in green under a autocomplete box after change
I have an autocomplete box that live updates the database with the selected entry when the user clicks off using blur. I am trying to add a "Updated" with a check icon next to it. I am basically trying to use where you would typically see a validation error but instead in green a success message. My code so far:
<v-autocomplete
    label="Analyst"
    v-model="item.analyst.internal_user_number"
    :items="AnalystsData"
    item-value="internal_user_number"
    :item-title="item=>`${item.first_name} ${item.last_name}`"
    variant="outlined"
    rounded
    hide-details
    class="my-5"
    density="compact"
    @blur="updateAssigments(item)"
/>

What would be the best approach to do this? I have tried to use the message slot but it did not work for some reason but I could have been using it incorrectly.

"how to" questions aren't exactly appropriate for Stack Overflow because it leads to opinionated answers.  Your approach seems fine and depends on the exact code you tried, which you did not show.  Include that code in your question and then others can point out any mistakes or offer objective answers on how to fix. I will say the message slot requires use of the messages prop which is not present in your current code.
